# Combobox SelectedValue Doesn't Show?

Tags: c#, combobox, microsoft-metro, store

I have created a combobox in xaml like this:

```
ComboBox x:Name="cbTest" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValue="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="250" SelectionChanged="cbTest_SelectionChanged"/>
```

And the Combobox is filled with the following ItemSources:

```
cbTest.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Left", "Right", "Center" };
```

I see the 3 strings in the Combobox, but it doesn't show the SelectedValue what I choose before. This is the property:

```
private short _test;
public short Test
{
    get
    {
        return _test;
    }
    set
    {
        _test = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Test gives me the following data: "Left". So, I get data but the binding isn't working!

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably a typo in the question - but your property returns _Test with an upper case T and sets _test with a lower case t, which would give you these symptoms, especially if _Test is an actual variable you've defined elsewhere..

Comment: Also your Items are strings, but the data type of Test is short, which would cause problems.

Comment: Ah, sorry! It's a type fail, it's in my solution "return _test".
That's not the problem. But thanks!

Comment: Hello @sa_ddam213 and Daniel, I have tried to change it to "string" but it's still not working

Comment: try `SelectedItem="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay}" `

Comment: Hmm.. Still not working...

Comment: I found the problem. What I did was change the text from Left to a new string called "Links" in dutch. When I use the Left,Right and Center then it's working. Thanks for all! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cant convert `System.String` to `System.Int16`(short), and you can't parse either because "Left", "Right", "Center" are not numbers.

Try using `string` as your `SelectedValue`

```
private string _test;
public string Test
{
    get
    {
        return _test;
    }
    set
    {
        _test = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I do when I select them:

`            string Test;

            if (cbTest.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                test= "Left";
                _vm.Test = test;
            }
            else if (cbTest.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                test = "Right";
                _vm.Test = test;
            }
            else if (cbTest.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                test = "Center";
                _vm.Test= test;
            }`